# Android: how to use the current theme's colors in a drawable xml?

Tags: android, xml, runtime, android-theme, xml-drawable

I have defined two themes with different primary, primary dark, primary light and accent colors.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_2</item>
</style>
```

AppTheme is default for `<application/>`
Then I set AppTheme2 in specific activities.

In a drawable file xml I'm using the same primary colors of AppTheme defined in colors.xml

The drawable is used in many activities from both themes, so when there is AppTheme2 I see the different colors.
Is there a way to make the drawable use the colors of the current theme for the current activity?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use this attribute to get color from currently used theme:

```
android:color="?colorPrimary"
```

This is possible only for android 5.0 or higher.

Comment: is there anyway to do this in Android 4? or do i have to make this progrommatically?

Comment: looks like it... https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: sadly it doesn't work for my xamarin Project, after changing gradle i get weird exceptions

Comment: how to do this programmatically?

Comment: @AnishKumar did you find any solution ?

Comment: How to do programmatically? I Tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489543/6333971 but it didn't work

Comment: Note that it works for Android < 5.0 if it isn't used in drawable. In drawable it won't report any error in xml, but it will crash when you try to reference this drawable's xml