# How do I set the text color to default in Android Studio from the code?

Tags: android-studio, colors

I have an EditText in my app that checks the user’s input on each change, and sets the text color to `R.color.red_error_text` when the input is malformatted. When the input is fine again, the color should change back to the default, which depends on the currently set theme. Is there a way to unset the value, i.e. a code equivalent to clearing the textColor field in the design editor or deleting the corresponding entry from the XML?

Alternatively, can I set the text color to `?attr/textColorPrimary` from the code?

I’m aware I can query the currently set theme whenever the color should change, and then set the color manually; but then the code would have to be changed whenever a new theme is introduced or the app’s color scheme changes for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer at [How can I get the primary color from my app theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489509/how-can-i-get-the-primary-color-from-my-app-theme). Translated to Kotlin, the solution is:

```
fun resolveColor(id: Int): Int {
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(id, typedValue, true)
    return typedValue.resourceId
}
```

Then we can call

```
editInput.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,
    resolveColor(R.attr.editTextColor)))
```

to set the text color in the currently set app theme, including day/night themes. `resolveColor(R.attr.someThemeColor)` also seems to work for any other color that is defined in the `theme.xml`s.